# Trying to prove an inequality

Tags: inequalities, global-optimization

I am working on a problem and for that purpose, I need to prove the following inequality. Let $t\in [0,1]$ and set
$$
z_0=1-4t(1-t)\sin^2(4x)\\
z_1=1-4z_0(1-z_0)\sin^2(3x)
$$
I need to show that for any $t\in [0,1]$ and $x$
$$
256t(1-t)z_0z_1 (\sin(x)\sin(2x)\sin(3x)\sin(4x))^2<3/2.   
$$
Using a tedious case by case analysis, we have been able to show this, but I wonder if this type of inequality is considered  or studied before in the literature or one can prove this with a conceptual or less calculational method.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_k = \sin^2 kx, \, k = 1, 2, 3, 4$. Then
$$a_2 = 4a_1(1 - a_1), 
\quad a_3 = a_1(3 - 4a_1)^2, \quad a_4 = 16a_1(1 - a_1)(1 - 2a_1)^2. \tag{1}$$

Let $y = 4t(1 - t)$
and $w = a_4y (1 - a_4y)$.

The desired inequality is written as
$$256 a_1 a_2 a_3^2 w^2 
- 64 a_1a_2a_3 w + \frac32 > 0. \tag{2}$$

**Case 1**: $a_1a_2 a_3 < \frac{3}{32}$

Using $w \le 1/4$, we have $- 64 a_1a_2a_3 w + \frac32
\ge - 64 a_1a_2a_3 \cdot \frac14 + \frac32 > 0.$
The desired result follows.

**Case 2**: $a_1a_2 < 3/8$

We have
$$256 a_1 a_2 a_3^2 w^2 
- 64 a_1a_2a_3 w + \frac32
= 4a_1a_2(8a_3w - 1)^2 + \frac{3 - 8a_1a_2}{2} > 0.$$

**Case 3**: $a_1a_2a_3 \ge \frac{3}{32}$ and $a_1a_2 \ge 3/8$

The inequality (2) is written as
$$8a_1a_2 (8a_3 w - 1)^2 > 8a_1a_2 - 3.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$\sqrt{8a_1a_2} (8a_3w - 1) < -\sqrt{8a_1a_2 - 3}.$$

From (1), we have
$a_1 a_2 = 4a_1^2(1 - a_1)$
and $a_1a_2a_3 = 4a_1^3(1 - a_1)(3 - 4a_1)^2$.

Thus, we have $4a_1^2(1 - a_1) \ge 3/8$
and $4a_1^3(1 - a_1)(3 - 4a_1)^2 \ge 3/32$ which imply
$$a_1 \in (39/100, 13/20). $$

Using (1), we have $a_4 = 16a_1(1 - a_1)(1 - 2a_1)^2 < 1/2$.
Then, it is easy to prove that $w = a_4y(1 - a_4y) \le a_4(1 - a_4)$.

Thus, it suffices to prove that
$$\sqrt{8a_1a_2} [8a_3a_4(1 - a_4) - 1] < -\sqrt{8a_1a_2 - 3}$$
or
$$\sqrt{8a_1a_2 - 3} < \sqrt{8a_1a_2} [1 - 8a_3a_4(1 - a_4)]. $$

Using (1),
we have $1 - 8a_3a_4(1 - a_4)
= 1 - 128a_1^2(3 - 4a_1)^2(1 - a_1)(1 - 2a_1)^2(8a_1^2 - 8a_1 + 1)^2
> 0$.

It suffices to prove that
$${8a_1a_2 - 3} < {8a_1a_2} [1 - 8a_3a_4(1 - a_4)]^2 $$
or
$$3 - 128a_1a_2a_3a_4(1 - a_4)(4a_3a_4^2 - 4a_3a_4 + 1) > 0. \tag{3}$$
(*Note*: Actually, (3) is true for all $a_1\in [0, 1]$.)

We split into two cases:

(1) If $a_1 \in [9/20, 13/20)$,
using $4a_3a_4^2 - 4a_3a_4 + 1 \le 4a_3a_4 - 4a_3a_4 + 1 = 1$ and $a_1a_2 = 4a_1^2(1 - a_1) < 3/5$ and $1 - a_4 \le 1$, it suffices to prove that
$$3 - 128\cdot \frac35 \cdot a_3a_4 > 0$$
or (using (1))
$$15 - 6144a_1^2(3 - 4a_1)^2(1 - a_1)(1 - 2a_1)^2 > 0$$
which is true.

(2) If $a_1 \in (39/100, 9/20)$,
it is not difficult to prove that $128a_1a_2a_3 = 512a_1^3(1 - a_1)(3 - 4a_1)^2 < \frac{424}{11}$ (actually for all $a_1\in [0, 1]$), and it suffices to prove that
$$3 - \frac{424}{11} \cdot a_4(1 - a_4)(4a_3a_4^2 - 4a_3a_4 + 1) > 0 \tag{4}$$
which is true.

We are done.

*Remarks*: The proof for (4) is still complicated. I hope to see a simpler proof for it.

Comment: Dear @River. Many thanks for your response. Can you please tell me why we have a_4<1/2 in Fact 1?

Comment: @MOB I will edit.